# Find the coefficient of $ x^{12}$ in $(1-x^2)^{-5}$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $(1-x^2)^{-5}$

What can be said for $x^{17}$

Tried $\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^{5}}$=$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+5-1}{n}x^n$
not sure that i can do that with $x^2$

Comment: Calculate the first and second derivatives of $\frac{1}{1-x}$, can you see the pattern?

Comment: correct mistakes if the last formula

Comment: To handle $x^2$, first find the expansion for $(1-t)^{-5}$, then substitute $t\mapsto x^2$. This procedure lets you answer the question about $x^{17}$ before you even do any calculations.

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{5}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+5-1}{n}x^n$?  If so $\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^{5}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+5-1}{n}x^{2n}$

Comment: Just write down the power series, and find the inverse for it. It is possible to find the first N terms of the inverse of any power series in quadratic time with a trivial algorithm.

Comment: $\frac 1 {(1-x^2)^{-5}}$ is an even function. This means that only even powers will appear in its expansion. Therefore, the coefficient of $x^{17}$ is $0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$y=\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n$$
the first derivative is
$$\frac{-1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }nx^{n-1}$$
the fourth derivative 
$$\frac{24}{(1-x)^5}=\sum_{n=4}^{\infty }n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)x^{n-4}$$
let $x\rightarrow x^2$
$$\frac{24}{(1-x^2)^5}=\sum_{n=4}^{\infty }n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)x^{2n-8}$$
to find coefficient of $x^{12}$
let
$$2n-8=12$$
$$n=10$$
so the coefficient is
$$(10)(10-1)(10-2)(10-3)/24=210$$

Answer (score 2):

It's convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
[x^k](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^{12}]\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^5}
> &=[x^{12}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-5}{k}(-x^2)^{k}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{12}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+4}{4}x^{2k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{10}{4}\tag{3}\\
> &=210
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* of $\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^5}$
- In (2) we use the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we select the coefficient of the series with $k=6$ accordingly

*Note:* Since the function is even, the coefficient of $x^{17}$ is zero.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the inverse of the power series of $(1-x^2)^5$

this one is as follows:

$[1,0,-5,0,10,0,-10,0,5,0,-1,0,0\dots$

we calculate its inverse like we would for any other power series from left to right (the algorithm is similar to that of synthetic division of a polynomial).

$[1,0,5,0,15,0,35,0,70,0,126,0,210$.

So the coefficient of $x^{12}$ is $210$ and for $x^{17}$ is clearly $0$.

---

I wrote a quadratic time algorithm to find the first $n+1$ terms of the inverse of a power series $P$ (given the first $n$ terms of P$).

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX=10010; // this is just the max size we work with
double P[MAX]; // here we store the coefficients of the power series
double I[MAX]; // here we store the coefficients of P^-1
int main(){
    int n; // the number of terms
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%lf",&P[i]); // here we read the first n coefficients of P
    }
    I[0]=1/P[0]; // the constant term of the inverse is the inverse of P[0]
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        double sum=0;
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){// calculate the value of the i'th term without I[i]P[0]
            sum+=I[j]*P[i-j];
        }
        I[i]=-sum/P[0]; // then I[i] must be -sum/P[0]
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){// this just prints the result
        printf("%g ",I[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noted: the negative binomial theorem, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html, gives
$$\frac{1}{(1-y)^{5}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+5-1}{n}y^n$$
Now replace $y$ with $x^2$ to get
$$\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^{5}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+5-1}{n}x^{2n}$$
For the coefficient of $x^{12}$, use n=6.
For $x^{17}$ the coefficient must be zero since all terms will have even powers.